# PywinAuto - application closes when I click on button to load the grid

Tags: pywinauto

After I click on "`LoadXML`" button application is closing  before loading the grid (usually it takes 5- 10secs to load it )

This issue is there when I use POM concept in `PyWinauto`.

But normally works well when I add all the code in the test file only.

```
def loadXML(self):   
   try:
      txtxml.set_edit_text("path of the xml file")
      self.sme.child_window(auto_id="btnloadxml").click_input() //failing after click on button ,application closed
      sleep(5)
      defv = self.sme.child_window(auto_id="dataGrid1")
      defv.wait('ready')
      sleep(2)
      return true
except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            raise
```